# Puppet service attributes based on hiera lookup and if else. Is this a bonehead rookie mistake?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I would like modify service attributes based on a hiera lookup.  So far I have tried the following and get an Invalid value "$foo::params::foo_ensure"  Valid values are stopped and running."  If this is a terrible way to do this, then what would you suggest?

```
class foo::params {

  $manage_foo = hiera('foo::active', false)

  if $manage_foo  {
    $foo_enable = true
    $foo_ensure = 'running'
   }

  else {
    $foo_enable = false
    $foo_ensure = 'stopped'
   }
```

}

```
class foo {

  include foo::params

  service {'foo':
    ensure    => '$foo::params::foo_ensure',
    enable    => '$foo::params::foo_enable',
   }
```

Many thanks from a puppet rookie!

Answer (score 1):

You are single quoting the variables. No variable interpolation is done when using single quotes. You essentially are saying that:

`ensure` LITERALLY `==` the string `$foo::params::foo_ensure`

AND

`enable` LITERALLY `==` the string `$foo::params::foo_enable`

It should look as below:

```
class foo {
  include foo::params

  service { 'foo':
    ensure => $foo::params::foo_ensure,
    enable => $foo::params::foo_enable
  }
}
```

You do not need ANY quotes here because you are not performing any string interpolation. If you really wanted to use quotes then you would use double quotes:

```
ensure => "${foo::params::foo_ensure}",
enable => "${foo::params::foo_enable}"
```

Take a look at [this documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation)

Another thing of note. The `include foo::params` is not needed here. There are no resources in the `params` class. A common pattern would be for the base class to `inherit` from `params`.

#### params.pp

```
class foo::params {
  $foo_enable = false
  $foo_ensure = 'stopped'
}
```

#### init.pp

```
class foo (
  $ensure = $foo::params::foo_ensure,
  $enable = $foo::params::foo_enable
) inherits foo::params {
  service { 'foo':
    ensure => $ensure,
    enable => $enable
  }
}
```

Then you can do away with the `hiera('foo::active', false)` and you can just use hiera to override the defaults like below:

```
foo::enable: true
foo::ensure: 'running'
```

This can be further simplified by doing away with the `params` class altogether and supplying the defaults in the main class.

#### init.pp (without params)

```
class foo (
  $ensure = 'stopped',
  $enable = false
) {
  service { 'foo':
    ensure => $ensure,
    enable => $enable
  }
}
```

The above class would use the same `hiera` data as the example above it.